# cassandra ec2 node is shutting down Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException

Tags: cassandra

This is the log  I see

Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/dev_fortis_mtd/explanationofbenefit-5fb6576031e511ec8611d5b080c74d01/snapshots/dropped-166672
6203042-explanationofbenefit/mc-1-big-Summary.db -> /var/lib/cassandra/data/dev_fortis_mtd/explanationofbenefit-5fb6576031e511ec8611d5b080c74d01/mc-1-big-Summary.d
b: Operation not permitted
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createLink(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:476) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
at java.nio.file.Files.createLink(Files.java:1086) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:100) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
... 23 common frames omitted
ERROR [InternalResponseStage:6] 2022-10-25 19:30:03,044 DefaultFSErrorHandler.java:66 - Stopping transports as disk_failure_policy is stop
ERROR [InternalResponseStage:6] 2022-10-25 19:30:03,044 StorageService.java:518 - Stopping gossiper
WARN [InternalResponseStage:6] 2022-10-25 19:30:03,044 StorageService.java:360 - Stopping gossip by operator request
INFO [InternalResponseStage:6] 2022-10-25 19:30:03,044 Gossiper.java:1683 - Announcing shutdown
INFO [InternalResponseStage:6] 2022-10-25 19:30:03,046 StorageService.java:2480 - Node /172.X.X.X state jump to shutdown

Answer (score 1):

looks like a problem with mc-1-big-Summary.db for the dev_fortis_mtd.explanationofbenefit table, can you check the data dir to see if mc-1... has a complete sstable set? If not, can you remove the incomplete set and then repair this table to pull data from another node in the cluster?